# Looking for implementing a centralized git repository... with a catch

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2010, git, centralized

The idea behind what I am wanting to do is to create a centralized server on a linux system. I understand how to set this up, and already have. Next I would like to set up git on a windows system, aka the client, which I understand is possible through msysgit, and gitextensions. The problem though is that I am wanting to integrate the windows client to be able to push and pull visual studio files but keep the repositories on the linux server.  So in short my question is how to have a centralized server on linux for git, while the client on windows is able to push to this centralized server. Thanks in advance!

I solved my problem. What I wanted to do was to create a ssh connection between the server(linux) and the client (windows). I used tortoise git in this case with the git source control provider (visual studio integration). Just follow the steps within the link and anybody else who might have this problem will be set!

Links:

For tortoise setup: http://theswarmintelligence.blogspot.com/2009/11/windows-tortoisegit-client-for-linux.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the catch here?  This sounds like a completely standard use case.  It's probably best to use SSH as a transport to push to the server.  A couple of things to be aware of are:

- You should create your centralized repository as a bare repository (i.e. one without a working tree)
- If you have multiple users who will push to that repository, create a group for them on the Linux machine, and make sure that the permissions for the repository are appropriate, e.g.:

  ```
  git init --bare --shared=group newrepository.git
  chgrp -R developers newrepository.git
  ```

Or if you're going to have multiple repositories or need more sophisticated access control, you may want to look at using [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite#start) on the server.

On the client side, GitHub has a nice walkthrough for installing msysgit on Windows (and generating an SSH key) here:

- http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/

... and there are tutorials for gitextensions [on its site](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/).

Comment: I guess I am being stupid here :P because there really is no catch I guess I would just be pulling from the server with git extensions on windows, while as you said controlling permissions on the server. Thanks for your reply!